# ./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node Module parse failed

Tags: react-doc-viewer

./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:2) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

we are using next.js. i have a folder inside "app" called "DocViewer". Inside the folder are 3 files: helloworld.pdf; page.js; page.tsx. here is the code for page.js and page.tsx.

page.js:

```
import DocViewer, { DocViewerRenderers } from "@cyntler/react-doc-viewer";

function Document() {

  const docs = [
    { 
      uri: require("./prova.pdf"),
      fileType: "pdf",
      fileName: "prova.pdf"
    }, 
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Document</h1>
      <DocViewer documents={docs} pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers} 
      style={{height:1000}}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Document;
```

and here is page.tsx:

```
import DocViewer, { DocViewerRenderers } from "@cyntler/react-doc-viewer";

  
  export default async function DocumentViewer() {
  
    const docs = [
        { 
          uri: require("./helloworld.pdf"),
          fileType: "pdf",
          fileName: "helloworld.pdf"
        }, 
      ];
  
    return (
      <main>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-8">
        <div>
            <h1>Document</h1>
            <DocViewer documents={docs} pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers} 
            style={{height:1000}}
            />
        </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    );
  }
```

I tried pretty much everything i could find online.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.